# How to allow users to log in by multiple email addresses?

Tags: authentication-authorization, 10

I'm trying to find a way to allow users to log in by email address when they have multiple email addresses registered on my site.

I'm using the [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration) module to allow users to register with an email address.

Then I can use the [Alternative User Emails](https://www.drupal.org/project/alternative_user_emails) module to save all the old email addresses when users change their email addresses. These old email addresses are stored in a separate database table.

The email registration module uses [`user_load_by_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/8.1.x) to get the user account when logging in. I think that overriding this is probably the simplest way, but there is no `hook_user_load_by_mail()` as far as I can tell.

So it looks like my options are:

- Hacking core to override `user_load_by_mail()`
- Patching the *Email Registration* module to check the table added by the *Alternative User Emails* module

Is there a way to glue these together in a custom module without hacking any module?
Ideally, I'd be able to write my own custom module that builds on top of core and contributed modules.

Comment: Decorating service user.auth is a good choice for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the Alternative User Emails module supports this functionality out of the box-- it modifies core's email queries to return alternative emails as well.

There was a bug in the module that prevented this from working in all cases, but that has now been fixed.

So the solution here is as simple as "install both Email Registration and Alternative User Emails, and they will work together seamlessly."